# Facebook Pagetab Request Dialogue Notification Shows and Goes

Tags: facebook

I am using request dialogue in facebook page tab. It shows the multifriend selector dialogue and once I sent the request, the user gets the notification and disappears after a while. and It never exists in the notification.

Here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>


<p>
  <input type="button"
    onclick="sendRequestToRecipients(); return false;"
    value="Send Request to Users Directly"  />
  <input type="text" value="User ID" name="user_ids" />
  </p>
<p>
<input type="button"
  onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"
  value="Send Request to Many Users with MFS" />
</p>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : xxxx,
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true,
  });
};
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {
       return;
       }
   js = d.createElement('script');
   js.id = id; 
   js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>

<script>
function sendRequestToRecipients() {
        var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request',
          to: user_ids, 
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request'
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
      }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know its been long time..did u find any solution to fix this problem am also facing the same

Comment: I can't remember since It's been a long time. But I do remember changing to an application from PageTab.

Answer (score 0):

> the user gets the notification and disappears after a while.

Can you be more specific?

AFAIK it is normal that requests that get no user response are removed automatically after a while.

> and It never exists in the notification.

Meaning what?